# Табличный вывод данных в Python. Входные данные - список в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, print, многомерные-списки

Прошу помочь разобраться в решении задачи (условие в Приложении).

Написал следующий код:

```
tableData = [['apples','oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
            ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]


def printTable():
    for lists in tableData:
        new_list = []
        for values in lists:
            width = len(values)
            new_list.append(width)
        new_list.sort()

        for values in lists:
            values = values.rjust(new_list[-1])
            print(values)




printTable()
```

Но код не до конца решает задачу. 
Прошу посодействовать, чтобы данные выводились именно по столбцам и с выравниваем `rjust()`.
Спасибо!

---

---

**Приложение**

[image: Задача]

Answer (score 4):

```
def printTable(data):
    cols = len(data)
    rows = len(data[0])
    col_width = [max(map(len, col)) for col in data]
    templates = ['{:>%d}' % width for width in col_width]

    for row in range(rows):
        print('\t'.join([templates[col].format(data[col][row]) for col in range(cols)]))



tableData = [['apples','oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
            ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

printTable(tableData)

#   apples  Alice    dogs
#  oranges    Bob    cats
# cherries  Carol   moose
#   banana  David   goose
```

**UPD** (*вариант попроще*):

```
def printTable(data):
    cols = len(data)
    rows = len(data[0])

    col_width = []
    for col in data:
        col_width.append(len(sorted(col, key=len)[-1]))

    for row in range(rows):
        result = []
        for col in range(cols):
            result.append(data[col][row].rjust(col_width[col]))
        print('\t'.join(result))
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вижу, что вы используете регулярки. Но данный пример из главы, где еще не было регулярок. Как-то без них можно код написать?

Comment: а генераторы списков и функция `map` уже пройдены? это просто форматированный вывод, не регулярное выражение, ведь модуль `re` не импортируется

Comment: @АскарСакенов, `{:>%d}` это не регулярка, это формат шаблона строки, который нужен для работы функции `format`, например `{:>5} {:>20}.format(4, "abc")`

Comment: @slippyk, в первом варианте у вас в функции используется `tableData`, это ведь опечатка и там должно было быть `data`? А во втором варианте можно использовать: `col_width = [len(max(col, key=len)) for col in data]`

Comment: @gil9red исправил, спасибо. второй вариант старался писать максимально просто и понятно, потому как не знаю на какой странице учебника автор и что он успел изучить

Comment: Только начинаю изучать питон. Начал с книги "Автоматизация рутинных задач с помощью Python" автор - Эл Свейгарт. (задача на 188 странице). Все читал и делал по порядку.  Генераторы и функция `map` не пройдены.

Answer (score 2):

```
def printTable():
    mx = tuple('{:>%s}' % max(map(len, s)) for s in tableData)
    for items in zip(*tableData):
        print(*(m.format(i) for m, i in zip(mx, items)))
        # или print(*(i.rjust(a, ' ') for i, a in zip(items, mx)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
def printTable(tableData):
    cols = len(tableData)
    rows = len(tableData[0])
    new_list = [ [" " for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows) ]
    maxLen   = 0
    for i, lists in enumerate(tableData):
        for j, values in enumerate(lists):
            new_list[j][i] = values
            if len(values) > maxLen: maxLen = len(values) 

    for values in new_list:
        print("{:>{maxLen}}{:>{maxLen}}{:>{maxLen}}".format(*values, maxLen=maxLen))


tableData = [['apples','oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob',     'Carol',    'David'],
             ['dogs',  'cats',    'moose',    'goose']]

printTable(tableData)
```

---

```
  apples   Alice    dogs
 oranges     Bob    cats
cherries   Carol   moose
  banana   David   goose
```

Answer (score 1):

По этой книге тоже учусь, вот мною собранное решение, оно простое.

```
tableData = [['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Cherry', 'Bananes'],
             ['Alise', 'Bobe', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['Dogs', 'Cats', 'Elk', 'Goose']]

for x, y, z in zip(*tableData):
    print(x.rjust(10), y.rjust(10), z.rjust(10))
```

Comment: Почему именно **10**?

Answer (score 1):

Эта задачка, из книги, заставила изрядно попотеть и потрепать себе нервы. Ведь до этого не было всех этих (пока что) сложных способов решения которые предлагают на форумах в сети. Вот что у меня вышло руководствуясь только тем, что давала нам книга ранее(ну или почти только тем, из стороннего тут только end='') :

```
tableData = [['apples','oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
        ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
         ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]


def printTable(somelist):
    list_of_len = [] # Сюда запишем длину всех объектов(слов) из списков списков
    max_len_element = 0 # Сюда запишем длину самого длинного слова (по ней и будем равняться)

    for item in tableData: # Итерируемся по спискам списка tableData
        for i in item: # Итерируемся по словам
            list_of_len.append(len(i)) # Записываем в список длину слов
    for max in list_of_len: # Теперь итерируемся по созданому нами списку длин слов
        if max > max_len_element: # Если значение больше чем наша переменная  max_len_element
            max_len_element = max # То мы переписываем переменную max_len_element на это новое значение

    for iter in range(len(tableData[1])): # Тут итератор обьектов внутри списков (от 0 до 4)
        for strings in somelist: # Тут ходим по строкам(спискам) списка tableData (от 0 до 2)
            print(strings[iter].rjust(max_len_element), end='') # Выводим обьект строки через индекс, форматируя сразу отступы
        print('\n', end='') # Тут после каждой итерации строки(списка) списка tableData, переходим на новую строку

printTable(tableData)
```

Comment: Я исправил вам отступы.

Answer (score 0):

'''Решение задачи только с помошью пройденого материал из книги Автоматизация рутиных задач ...  '''

```
def print_table(td):
    new_list = []
    length = 0
    for i in range(len(td[0])):
        new_list.append(f'{td[0][i]} {td[1][i]} {td[2][i]}')
        if len(new_list[i]) > length:
            length = len(new_list[i])
    for v in new_list:
        print(v.rjust(length))

table_data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
              ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'], 
              ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

print_table(table_data)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]